# With GAS, how to keep columns width when copy and past TAB from sheet to doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

My code below imports to a Gdocument a table (rows and col) selected in Gsheet but my problem is that the columns width are not kept when the tab is copied in the Gdocument so I spend hours to set again the columns width in the Gdocument.

Do you have any suggestion to help my tab to keep its columns width?

Here is my code :

```
function readFromSpreadsheetAndWriteOnDoc() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName('Feuille 1');
var selection = ss.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
var srcData = sourcesheet.getRange(selection).getValues();

var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1a2X5oZhW2aY-p15vMvvPt9wvhm1UVHJU5_3ZJ3-OCBo'
var body = doc.getBody();

body.insertParagraph(3, 'My Title').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).
setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
table = body.appendTable(srcData);

table.getRow(0).editAsText().setBold(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the width of specific cells using the Sheet API `get` method ([Documentation Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)). But you would need to do that for individual cells in each column (like the top cell in each column). Then you can use the `setColumnWidth()` method ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setcolumnwidthcolumnindex,-width)) to recreate the right sizes in thew table.

This process would be quite convoluted, I would suggest just using the `setColumnWidth()` method when you're building the table (`table.setColumnWidth()`, for example) to do it in a sort of manual way. This would allow you more control on specific cells.